# formatted json as a input for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'd like to include input of the step function to the payload of one of steps which is lambda that puts an event bridge event.

currently, I'm experimenting with the syntax as below:

Lambda task input:

"events_payloads.$": 'States.Format('{"Detail": {"Payload": {}, "status": "%s", "status_detail": "%s"}, "DetailType": "my_event"}', $.detail)'

but it ends up with an error. $.detail is filled-in by Format as a structure like this:

Invalid type for parameter Entries, value: {"Detail": {"Payload": {service_name=Res, service_version=abc, environment=test}, "status": "active", "status_detail": ""}, "DetailType": "my_event""}, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>",

so actually what I'd like to produce as input parameter is as a JSON with nested input payload. Anyone has a clue how to approach this?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Json/asl declaration for the given step (or the whole state machine). Input for the given step, and expected payload for the lambda?

Comment: I'd recommend you to try [data flow simulator](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/modeling-workflow-input-output-path-processing-with-data-flow-simulator/) to find a solution to your problem: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/modeling-workflow-input-output-path-processing-with-data-flow-simulator/